# Creating multiple HBox with same attributes

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, duplicates

I'm trying to dynamically add objects/elements by getting the data from the database.
What I'm trying to achieve is, I want to copy the same `HBox` with the same `attributes`, such as `FontAwesomeIcon` etc. However, I just want to change the labels.

This is what I'm trying to achieve.
[image: Example]

I want to be able to create multiple `HBox` dynamically, similar to the other ones, but just change the `Labels` which values I get from the database.

`FXML` Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
         prefWidth="700.0" stylesheets="@stylesheet.css" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text="Members">
            <graphic>
                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="GROUP" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#4D4D4D" size="14"/>
            </graphic>
            <content>
                <AnchorPane prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="700.0">
                    <children>
                        <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" prefHeight="381.0" prefWidth="172.0">
                            <content>
                                <VBox fx:id="vboxAdding" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="157.0"
                                      style="-fx-background-color: #4D4C4F;">
                                    <children>
                                        <ListView fx:id="sidebarListview" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="157.0"/>
                                        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" styleClass="HBox-Shadow">
                                            <children>
                                                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="SEARCH" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#B2B2B2"
                                                                     size="22"/>
                                                <TextField promptText="Search"
                                                           style="-fx-background-color: transparent;-fx-text-fill: white"
                                                           HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                </TextField>
                                            </children>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" top="5.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <HBox fx:id="sidebarMembers" onMouseClicked="#openSidebarMembers">
                                            <children>
                                                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#B2B2B2"
                                                                     size="22">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets top="3.0"/>
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </FontAwesomeIconView>
                                                <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label fx:id="sidebarName" text="Admin" textFill="WHITE">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0"/>
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                        <Label text="Administrator" textFill="WHITE"/>
                                                    </children>
                                                    <padding>
                                                        <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                                    </padding>
                                                </VBox>
                                            </children>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <HBox fx:id="sidebarMembers1" onMouseClicked="#openSidebarMembers">
                                            <children>
                                                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#B2B2B2"
                                                                     size="22">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets top="3.0"/>
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </FontAwesomeIconView>
                                                <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label fx:id="sidebarName1" text="Michael" textFill="WHITE">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0"/>
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                        <Label text="Administrator" textFill="WHITE"/>
                                                    </children>
                                                    <padding>
                                                        <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                                    </padding>
                                                </VBox>
                                            </children>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="172.0" prefHeight="381.0" prefWidth="538.0"
                              style="-fx-background-color: #4D4C4F;">
                            <children>
                                <Circle fx:id="bigImageView" fill="BLUE" radius="50.0">
                                    <VBox.margin>
                                        <Insets bottom="20.0" top="30.0"/>
                                    </VBox.margin>
                                </Circle>
                                <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label fx:id="summaryTitleName" text="Admin" textFill="WHITE">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font size="20.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label text="Administrator" textFill="WHITE">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font name="System Italic" size="15.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Separator prefWidth="200.0"/>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="170.0" prefWidth="528.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <VBox prefHeight="168.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="Full Name: Admin Admin" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="Position: Administrator" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="Hourly Rate: £19.99" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="Graduated: MDX University" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                            </children>
                                            <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets/>
                                            </HBox.margin>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                        </VBox>
                                        <VBox prefHeight="168.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="Languages: Java, C++, JavaScript" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="Country: United Kingdom" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="City: Wembley, London" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label text="Address: 64, Beverley Gardens" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="15.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                    <VBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                                    </VBox.margin>
                                                </Label>
                                            </children>
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                            <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets/>
                                            </HBox.margin>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Overview">
            <graphic>
                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="PIE_CHART" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#4D4D4D" size="14"/>
            </graphic>
            <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Control Panel">
            <graphic>
                <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="WRENCH" glyphStyle="-fx-fill:#4D4D4D" size="14"/>
            </graphic>
            <content>

            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

So how can I achieve this, is there a way to copy/paste an element into FXML, then just change the labels inside of that element?

The amount of `HBoxes` is not static, it depends on how many members I got on my database.

Comment: Maybe a `List` with a custom `ListCell`?

Comment: @trashgod But this won't give me the same layout/attributes that I want, right?

Comment: Please post [mcve]. The code should represent the question (dynamically add nodes) rather than your application.

Comment: I don't see why not; `ListCell` has all the CSS properties of `Labeled`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a reusable `HBox` fxml:

**NodeTemplate.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox fx:id="template" alignment="CENTER" style="fx-border-width: 3; -fx-border-color: blue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="NodeTemplateController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="content" text="" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

And its controller:

**NodeTemplateController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class NodeTemplateController{

    @FXML
    Label content;

    void setContent(String txt){
        content.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

Main container to which you keep adding `NodeTemplate` instances:

**Main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="200.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="add" text="Click To Add Nodes" textAlignment="CENTER" />
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0">
        <content>
          <VBox fx:id="containerPane"/>
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Use the controller of to add `NodeTemplate` instances on mouse click:

**MainController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MainController{

    @FXML
    private Pane containerPane;
    @FXML
    private Button add;

    private static int counter = 0;

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        add.setOnAction(e -> addNode());
    }

    private void addNode() {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            Node node  =  loader.load(getClass().getResource("NodeTemplate.fxml").openStream());
            containerPane.getChildren().add(node);
            //get the controller 
            NodeTemplateController controller = (NodeTemplateController)loader.getController();
            controller.setContent("Node number "+ counter++); //set label 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To test it, use:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
      Parent root  =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      primaryStage.show();
}
```