# JavaFX: Is there a way of using the constructor of the controller class along with the initialise method?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

[image]

The picture above shows a UI design that I wish to implement in my project.

As you can see, there are 2 similar rectangles with varying details in them. These details are from a custom object `Bell` in my project. There is a `List` of `Bell`s that needs to have their details displayed like shown above.

My plan was to create a class called `BellBox` that will represent the rectangles containing the details of a single `Bell`. This class will have a method called `build()` that will load the FXML file named "BellBoxFMXL.fxml". The FXML file contains an `AnchorPane` as the root and has the necessary containers to represent all the information of a `Bell`. The `AnchorPane` will then be returned.

The `BellBox` class:

```
public class BellBox {

    protected final Bell bell ;
    protected final int index ;

    public BellBox(Bell bell, int index) {
        this.bell = bell;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public Pane build() throws IOException {
        Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource("/model/BellBoxFXML.fxml"))) ;

        return pane ;
    }
}
```

Now, for the controller class. The controller class of the FXML file is called `BellBoxController`. Remember I said that the `AnchorPane` will have containers to show the details of a `Bell` object? Yeah, so I decided have the controller class to extend the `BellBox` class. The reason was so that when the `initialize()` method is called, the labels can be updated using the `bell` attribute/property of the `BellBox` class.

The `BellBoxController` class:

```
public class BellBoxController extends BellBox implements Initializable {

    public Label indexLbl ;

    public BellBoxController(Bell bell, int index) {
        super(bell, index) ;
        System.out.println("called with " + index) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        System.out.println("initializing labels and stuff...");
        this.indexLbl.setText("#" + (this.index + 1));
    }
}
```

However, when I compiled the program and tried to run it, it crashed with a `LoadException` error.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/.../model/BellBoxFXML.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at model.BellBox.build(BellBox.java:20)
    at mainapp.Main.openHomeView(Main.java:126)
    at mainapp.Main.start(Main.java:109)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: model.BellBoxController
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.BellBoxController.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    ... 25 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I also noticed that both output statements in the constructor and `initialize()` method were not displayed in the console. Could someone explain to me why this is and how I could go about to achieve what I hope to do? And point out what I'm doing wrong (if that's the case).

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: you might want to set the controller before loading (vs. have the fx:controller attribute in the fxml) or set a controllerFactory - both allows you to have constructor with parameters

Comment: @kleopatra I've edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: A compete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800394/230513).

Comment: The exception occurs because the `FXMLLoader` is looking for, and cannot find, a no-parameter constructor. The `BellBoxController` is never instantiated because the no-parameter constructor doesn’t exist, so you never see your concise output.

Comment: Your controller should probably not be a subclass of `BellBox`, but should just have a reference to one (“favor aggregation over inheritance”). You can pass it a reference using the techniques shown at https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187963/2189127, or use a `controllerFactory`.

Comment: If you are going to implement build() then you should probably make BellBox implement Builder<Region>.  And rename it to something like BellBoxBuilder.  In build() instantiate the FXMLLoader and then get the Controller from it.  Put some methods in BellBoxController to set the bell and index fields.  Then ncall them from build().

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342864/2189127. You can think of `BellBox` as the model for the individual components.

Comment: And finally, you could also consider a `ListView<Bell>` here, with a `cellFactory` returning a cell which used the FXML. You would just need the `Bell` and could remove `BellBox` entirely, as the cells already have access to the item’s index.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a custom node using `FXML`. If so, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The MVC from the link @James_D shared solves the problem.